# Cycle a window through monitors in Gnome ("wraparound" effect)

Tags: gnome, 20.04, multiple-monitors

I have three monitors side by side and I have found the following shortcuts in Gnome

1. Shift+Super+Left (move to left monitor)
2. Shift+Super+Right (move to right monitor)

Unlike Unity, nothing happens when I use the shortcut to move left on a window already in the leftmost monitor. In Unity, it moves back to the rightmost monitor (i.e., the rightmost monitor is considered at the left of the leftmost monitor, like the "[wraparound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wraparound_(video_games))" feature in a video game). Can I get the Unity-like wraparound in Gnome for both shortcuts?

Comment: Suffering from same issue. Couldn't find a solution yet. In unity you could use "put" in compiz config settings and that would cycle it

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with the extension [CHC-E - Custom Hot Corners - Extended - GNOME Shell Extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4167/custom-hot-corners-extended/). I defined a shortcut key for “Move Window to Next Monitor” in Windows - Relocations. And then I passed that shortcut to [Input Remapper](https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper). And it’s working great.